# Tinymce 4 inline css content applied to page instead of div only

Tags: css, tinymce

I have a div and apply the latest version of tinymce (4.2.5) to it, including some of my websites stylesheets.

When I use the editor old fashioned way the loaded css is only applied to the div I'm attaching tinymce to. Like a charm.

But I want to use the `inline: true` option. When I use that all the css is applied to the complete page of the application, not only the div.

Is this expected behavior? Or should I look for another approach? My main reason to use the inline feature is that it keeps the toolbar visible on scrolling. Unfortunately tinymce loads different sets of html for the inline and fixed toolbar (for example, the menu bar and icon/tool bar are separate div's. On inline they have a parent div) so just applying the same or similar css isn't working out.

Anybody has any tips or tricks for me? Or should I accept the limitations of one or the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to accept the limitations.

Both editor modes need different css for the UI and in inline mode it seems to be necessary to apply it to the complete page (even though you don't like that).